# Copy Files and Folders recursively with Powershell

Tags: powershell, file-copying

In a vbscript, I have some code to copy files and folders recursively using a powershell command:

```
pCommand = "Copy-Item " & sourcePath & " " & destinationPath & " -Recurse -Force"
oShell.Run("powershell.exe -Command "" & " & pCommand & """"), 1, True
```

This used to work fine up until a couple of months ago but now, and I'm not sure the reason why, it doesn't copy all the files and not all of the structure is retained either.

For example, the structure is as followed:

```
sourcePath\Report\Act1\Row0

sourcePath\Report\Act2\Row0

sourcePath\Report\Act3\Row0

...

sourcePath\Report\icons

sourcePath\Report\Resources\Checkpoints
```

On the destination path, I end up with:

```
destinationPath\Report\Act1\Row0

destinationPath\Report\Act2   (subfolder Row0 is not created)

destinationPath\Report\Act3   (subfolder Row0 is not created)

...

destinationPath\Report\icons => folder created but files within the folder are not copied
```

During execution, I keep seeing these types of messages:

> Copy-Item : The target file "...\Report\Act3" is a directory, not a
>   file.

Has anything changed in Powershell? I can use objFSO.CopyFolder instead. It works fine but it's much slower.

Thanks

Comment: You may need to state the file extension

Comment: Well, i want all files copied. If I add "\*.*" on the source path, only the files not in subfolders are copied and if I add "\*.*" also on the destination path, nothing is copied